# Does Google Cloud platform have any blocked subnet ranges?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

Good afternoon,
I am trying to connect a Google Cloud VPN to an internal subnet and we are unable to get any communication between the private network and the cloud servers. I am able to reach these servers from a different subnet on a different VPN tunnel.

Comment: What are firewall rules configuration in your project? What are your IP range to access?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that VPN setup properly, meaning, it allows your private CIDR.
When you try to connect to cloud servers on which port you are trying to use ? if you have firewall rule allowing the private network on this port( can compare  firewall rules from working setup you have)

If still have no clue , enable 'flow logs' for the subnet and look for error.

please if add more specific details, we answer better.